# Get the current time of animation using script Unity3d

Tags: unity, unityscript

I want to know the current time of the played animation using script in Unity3d. I tried using `currentState.normalizedTime` but this time is not the time of the animation, like it's the time of the runtime I think. Any advice please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    int frameNumber = Mathf.FloorToInt(normalizedtimeOfFrame* totalFrames);
```

Answer (score 1):

You would use [AnimationState.time](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationState-time.html)

It can be larger than the length of the animation, so to get the value with this, you would need to modulo with the animation clip length.

```
float time = currentState.time % currentState.clip.length;
```

You can also use Normalized Time, but you would have to mulitply the value by the length instead of the animation ([AnimationClip.Length](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationClip-length.html))

```
float time = currentState.normalizedTime * currentState.clip.length;
```

Comment: But this is the animation time or the run time? Like what if after running my application I didn't play the animation until 5 seconds, would these 5 seconds included when using AnimationState.Time?

Comment: Sorry, I was still editing the question after I posted it.

Comment: I tried it and it gives this error `Error CS0117: 'UnityEngine.Animation' does not contain a definition for 'length' (CS0117) (Assembly-CSharp)`

Comment: You have to reference the actual animation instance.   Use currentState.clip.length;

Comment: it is still not working as it gives this error `Error CS1061: 'UnityEngine.AnimatorStateInfo' does not contain a definition for 'time' and no extension method 'time' accepting a first argument of type 'UnityEngine.AnimatorStateInfo' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061) (Assembly-CSharp)`

Comment: and this is the declaration of `currentState` : `AnimatorStateInfo currentState = my_Animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0);`